# Devise returns 401 on updated Rails 3.1 app with slightly custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, restful-authentication, warden

I can't seem to get a user logged into our admin panel after upgrading our app from Rails 2.3.x to Rails 3.1.3. I'm using the latest version of Devise, which at the time of this post is v1.5.3.

A `POST` to the `session#create` route returns a `401` response (and all the params look like they're going in properly); it happens when Warden tries to auth the user using one of Devise's strategies (`:database_authenticatable`). Here's my user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

I've got an overridden `Devise::SessionsController` in my `:admin` namespace (the logins are for admins only, and they've got their own site layout, thus the override). There's nothing special in the controller, really, other than the layout:

```
class Admin::SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
  layout "admin"
end
```

I do have slightly customized routes, and here's the code that I've got for that.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'admin/sessions' }
```

I have the `csrf_meta_tag` bit in my layout's headers, and my `ApplicationController` has the `protect_from_forgery` line in it. The form's errors are empty when it comes back to re-render the page.

I've stepped through the code (all the way into `lib/warden/proxy.rb`), and Warden doesn't seem to think the `:database_authenticatable` strategy I'm using is valid ([Warden's source code](https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L308) for that part). The user is a valid user… I've created it via an Rails `rails console` IRB session, from scratch, with a valid password and everything. I would hope it should recognize that as valid, right? Or am I even barking up the right tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I'm kind of a fool. After stepping into Devise's `authenticatable` strategy, it became clear to me that in my `devise.rb` configuration file (which I had copied in from another project and tweaked) had `:username` listed as an authentication_key, and not `:email` like it should have been. Changed it to `:email` and now it works.

In a related story, I now have a somewhat murky understanding of how Devise works with Warden.

Comment: This may be a bit old, but thanks - this is exactly what I was doing, only I had the authentication_key specified in the model, and kept overlooking it. Your post at least helped me find it.

Comment: Wait, is this Jerry Jones of Dashbuster fame?! Glad I could help!

Comment: Fame? I didn't know I had any fame from Dashbuster! Yeah, that's me alright.